# How to display a system notification in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, notifications

What is the best way to display system notifications with Python, preferably using tkinter for cross platform implementation (I am on OS X, so I'm also open to implementations that would allow integration with Notification Center)?

I want to show a self-destroying message, I mean something that would remain on screen for a few seconds and then would vanish way, but without interfering with user interaction. I don't want to use a messagebox because in requires the user to click in a button to dismiss the message window.

What do you recommend?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works for me. It shows the message as a popup and exits after 2 seconds.

```
from tkinter import *
from sys import exit
def popupError(s):
    popupRoot = Tk()
    popupRoot.after(2000, exit)
    popupButton = Button(popupRoot, text = s, font = ("Verdana", 12), bg = "yellow", command = exit)
    popupButton.pack()
    popupRoot.geometry('400x50+700+500')
    popupRoot.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tryed this but got an error. I created a new file with `from tkinter import *`, then your code, then `popupError("blablabla")`. I get this: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled.py", line 11, in <module>
    popupError("blablabla")
  File "Untitled.py", line 5, in popupError
    popupRoot.after(2000, exit)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 602, in after
    callit.__name__ = func.__name__
AttributeError: 'Quitter' object has no attribute '__name__'`

Comment: Oh... I missed this import statement: `from sys import exit`. Now it works.

Comment: Would it be easy to make the notification window have no title bar?